# Get 404 Not Found when accessing property of OData entity without key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-routing

I have routing OData problem combined with ASP.NET Core. I have the following classes

```
public class Publisher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration is

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   ...
   app.UseMvc(b =>
   {
        b.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100).Count();
        b.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "myRoute", routePrefix: "odata", model: GetEdmModel());
   });
}

private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Publisher>("Publisher");
    builder.EntitySet<Category>("Category");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

And of course controller

```
public class PublisherController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<string> GetCategory()
    {
        return _db.Publishers.Select(p => p.Category);
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<string> GetCategory([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return Ok(_db.Publishers.Where(p => p.Id == key).Select(p => p.Category));
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I am trying to make GET request with specific Id, like

```
http://localhost:port/odata/Publisher(1)/Category
```

all works fine and I get the result, but if I am trying to make

```
http://localhost:port/odata/Publisher/Category
```

I have 404 Not Found Exception

Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Mykhailo

That's related to the OData Url convention. for the Url convention about the property access, you can refer to http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/cs01/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.01-cs01-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc505773205 for detail.

`http://...../Category` is to access the property. Basically, we can access a property from an entity. `Publisher(1)` is an entity whose key value is 1, meanwhile  `Publisher` is the whole entity set. So, `http://localhost:port/odata/Publisher(1)/Category` is a valid OData Url path, but, `http://localhost:port/odata/Publisher/Category` is invalid. If you use the ODL Uri parser to parse the invalid path, you will get an exception.

Hope it can help.